# Faulty calculation in Schubert calculus: the number of lines on the intersection of two planes.

Tags: solution-verification, fake-proofs, schubert-calculus

As a easy test of the correctness of the results of Schubert calculus I tried to solve the following problem with the symbolic method.

Q: How many lines are there lying on the intersection of two planes in $\mathbb{P}^3$?

The correct answer is one, the intersection of two planes *is* a line. However in the following calculation I seem to find that there are none. Note that the lines on a plane $H$ are represented by $\Omega(L_i, H)\subseteq G_{1,3}$ for any line $L_i \subseteq H$. Therefore we must calculate the degree of $\Omega(1,2)^2$. Giambelli's formula yields that 
\begin{align*}\Omega(1,2) &= \det 
            \begin{pmatrix}
                \sigma(1) & \sigma(0)\\
                \sigma(2) & \sigma(1)
            \end{pmatrix} \\
            &= \sigma(1)^2 - \sigma(0)\sigma(2)
\end{align*}
Hence, by Pierri's formula 
\begin{align*}
    \Omega(1,2)^2 &= \Omega(1,2)\sigma(1)^2 - \Omega(1,2)\sigma(0)\sigma(2)\\
                &= \Omega(0,2)\sigma(1) - \Omega(0,1)\sigma(2)\\
                &= \Omega(0,1) - \Omega(0,1)\\
                &= 0
\end{align*}
Suggesting that $\deg \Omega(1,2)^2 = 0$.

What am I doing wrong here?

Note: I am using the notation of Kleiman and Laksov's [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2317421?seq=1) on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The faulty step is using $\Omega(1,2)\sigma(0)=\Omega(0,1).$ Pieri's formula gives
$$\Omega(1,2)\sigma(0)=\sum\Omega(b_0,b_1)$$
where the sum is over integers $b_0,b_1$ such that
$$0\leq b_0\leq 1<b_1\leq 2,\qquad b_0+b_1=1$$
There are no such choices of $b_0,b_1,$ so
$$\Omega(1,2)\sigma(0)=0.$$